# How to increase max upload file size for specific user roles in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

On my WordPress site, the Super Administrator user can upload up to 256 MB, but the editor users can only upload up 2 MB. How to increase it?

Answer (score 5):

My problem with this piece of code was solved.

```
/**
* Filter the upload size limit for non-administrators.
*
* @param string $size Upload size limit (in bytes).
* @return int (maybe) Filtered size limit.
*/
function filter_site_upload_size_limit( $size ) {
    // Set the upload size limit to 10 MB for users lacking the 'manage_options' capability.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        // 10 MB.
    $size = 1024 * 10000;
    }
    return $size;
}
add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'filter_site_upload_size_limit', 20 );
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_size_limit/#user-contributed-notes

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't increase it beyond the limits set by super user. So, if you found 2MB as the maximum value, it would be the maximum set by admin.

Comment: Thankful. I'm just looking for a place where I can get the maximum amount of file uploads for editor users, as the super administrator uploads. How can I do this in the WordPress admin panel or at the core of it? I searched a lot, but unfortunately I did not have any results.

Comment: You, as regular user, should talk to the administrators to make your account be allowed to upload such a big files that you want. Get in touch with them.

Comment: I am the owner of the site and the super administrator. My users have this problem that I do not know how to solve.

Comment: So you'll have to increase this variable. Here maybe you can find the solution: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/increase-media-file-maximum-upload-size-in-wordpress/

Comment: In the link above, the overall increase in upload volume is explained in general. I am a manager and now I can upload from the WordPress dashboard to 256 MB and I have no problems. But WordPress authors can upload files by default up to 2MB. I want to increase this 2 megabytes set to the WordPress core. This restriction is by default in the WordPress core and I did not use any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easy for each site inside Network Admin>Sites. Select the site you want to edit and once on the settings page scroll all the way to the bottom. You will see Upload limit setting. So if you as a superadmin created a site and need to have more upload limit you can do this. For a role setting the code mentioned above works.

Comment: There are no upload limit setting in Network Admin > Sites > [yoursite]. > Settings.